# Handling multiple variants of a marshmallow schema

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have a simple [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/) model, which I'm writing a REST API for:

```py
class Report(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    report_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.user_id'), index=True)
    report_hash = Column(Unicode, index=True, unique=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    uploaded_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
```

Then I have the corresponding [Marshmallow-SQLAlchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) schema:

```py
class ReportSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
```

However, in my rest API, I need to be able to dump and load slightly different variants of this model:

- When dumping all the reports (e.g. `GET /reports`), I want to dump all the above fields.
- When dumping a single report (e.g. `GET /reports/1`), I want to dump all this data, and also all associated relations, such as the associated `Sample` objects from the `sample` table (one report has many Samples)
- When creating a new report (e.g. `POST /reports`), I want the user to provide all the report fields except `report_id` (which will be generated), `report_hash` and `uploaded_at` (which will be calculated on the spot), and also I want them to include all the associated `Sample` objects in their upload.

How can I reasonably maintain 3 (or more) versions of this schema? Should I:

- Have 3 separate `ModelSchema` subclasses? e.g. `AggregateReportSchema`, `SingleReportSchema`, and `UploadReportSchema`?
- Have one mega-`ModelSchema` that includes all fields I could ever want in this schema, and then I subtract fields from it on the fly using the `exclude` argument [in the constructor](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema)? e.g. `ReportSchema(exclude=[])`?
- Or should I use inheritance and define a `class ReportBaseSchema(ModelSchema)`, and the other schemas subclass this to add additional fields (e.g. `class UploadReportSchema(ReportBaseSchema)`)?
- Something else?

Comment: I would do a mix of the 2 last solutions, but I dont know what is the most performant. My opinion on the first option is that it produces too much code. I'm very interested in what is the best performant/maintainable option here.

Comment: any light here? i am facing the same question!!

Comment: I've just posted an answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since asking this question, I've done a ton of work using Marshmallow, so hopefully I can explain somewhat.

My rule of thumb is this: **do as much as you can with the schema constructor (option #2), and only resort to inheritance (option #3) if you absolutely have to.** Never use option #1, because that will result in unnecessary, duplicated code.

The schema constructor approach is great because:

- You end up writing the least code
- You never have to duplicate logic (e.g. validation)
- The `only`, `exclude`, `partial` and `unknown` arguments to the schema constructor give you more than enough power to customize the individual schemas ([see the documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#schema))
- Schema subclasses can add extra settings to the schema constructor. For example [marshmallow-jsonapi](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-jsonapi) addds [`include_data`](https://marshmallow-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#compound-documents), which lets you control the amount of data you return for each related resource

---

My original post is a situation where using the schema constructor is sufficient. You should first define a schema that includes all possibly related fields, including relationships that might be a `Nested` field. Then, if there are related resources or superfluous fields you don't want to include in the response sometimes, you can simply use `Report(exclude=['some', 'fields']).dump()` in that view method.

However, an example I've encountered where using inheritance was a better fit was when I modelled the arguments for certain graphs I was generating. Here, I wanted general arguments that would be passed into the underlying plotting library, but I wanted the child schemas to refine the schema and use more specific validations:

```py
class PlotSchema(Schema):
    """
    Data that can be used to generate a plot
    """
    id = f.String(dump_only=True)
    type = f.String()
    x = f.List(f.Raw())
    y = f.List(f.Raw())
    text = f.List(f.Raw())
    hoverinfo = f.Str()


class TrendSchema(PlotSchema):
    """
    Data that can be used to generate a trend plot
    """
    x = f.List(f.DateTime())
    y = f.List(f.Number())
```