# How to send customized responses with marshmallow schemas?

Tags: python, json, flask, serialization, marshmallow

i'm trying to implement a JSON API using Flask and marshmallow but I'm struggling to send a response that looks like the following snippet by using a marshmallow schema.

```json
    {
    "recipeNames":
        [
            "scrambledEggs",
            "garlicPasta",
            "chai"
        ]
    }
```

My data looks like this (I'm using a json file as a database)

```json
    {
    "recipes": [
        {
            "ingredients": [
                "1 tsp oil",
                "2 eggs",
                "salt"
            ],
            "instructions": [
                "Beat eggs with salt",
                "Heat oil in pan",
                "Add eggs to pan when hot",
                "Gather eggs into curds, remove when cooked",
                "Salt to taste and enjoy"
            ],
            "name": "scrambledEggs"
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [
                "500mL water",
                "100g spaghetti",
                "25mL olive oil",
                "4 cloves garlic",
                "Salt"
            ],
            "instructions": [
                "Heat garlic in olive oil",
                "Boil water in pot",
                "Add pasta to boiling water",
                "Remove pasta from water and mix with garlic olive oil",
                "Salt to taste and enjoy"
            ],
            "name": "garlicPasta"
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [
                "400mL water",
                "100mL milk",
                "5g chai masala",
                "2 tea bags or 20 g loose tea leaves"
            ],
            "instructions": [
                "Heat water until 80 C",
                "Add milk, heat until 80 C",
                "Add tea leaves/tea bags, chai masala; mix and steep for 3-4 minutes",
                "Remove mixture from heat; strain and enjoy"
            ],
            "name": "chai"
        },
        {
            "ingredients": [
                "1 bagel",
                "2 tbsp butter"
            ],
            "instructions": [
                "cut the bagel",
                "spread butter on bagel"
            ],
            "name": "butteredBagel"
        }
    ]}
```

And i'm using a marshmallow schema that looks like this

```py
    class RecipeSchema(Schema):
    
        ingredients = fields.List(fields.Str())
        instructions = fields.List(fields.Str())
        name = fields.Str()
```

So far, I tried to use another schema completely just to have a single attribute named "recipeNames", but it feels wrong to implement a different schema for every variation of response we can send with the API.
I also tried just not using marshmallow, which worked, but then I can't really validate the data while it's transiting through the API.
Finally I tried using some context or some extension like pre_dump by reading the marshmallow doc and examples [Marshmallow examples](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html), [Context Doc](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/why.html#context-aware-serialization), but now I am kind of lost on what would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I guess this would be very close to doing aggregation after the data is loaded into the schema, but I couldn't found any documentation on such a thing in marshmallow.
Did anyone ever had this kind of problem?

---

**EDIT**
Maybe this question can help [Multiple Variants of schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57249800/handling-multiple-variants-of-a-marshmallow-schema), but I'm still not sure how to handle what I want to achieve

Comment: "it feels wrong to implement a different schema for every variation of response we can send with the API" Matter of preference but I don't think it is wrong. I often do it if only to simplify auto-documentation of the API (using apispec).